# I am a shareholder but am not invited to shareholder meetings

Tags: shareholder-meeting

I have been a shareholder in a company for about 14 years and have never been invited to a shareholder meeting. The company is still around and over 10 times the size that it used to be. How do I go about finding the person I need to contact to get myself invited and find out what I have been missing, and what do I say to them?

Comment: Doesn't the company has an address? A CEO? Any representative?

Comment: You might want to include some information about your location. It wouldn't shock me if this kind of thing varied by jurisdiction.

Comment: The company does have an address and a CEO and I do know both of these things but I am unclear on whether sending some sort of snail mail letter or email to their newest CEO is the best course of action. I started a conversation with one of their founders on LinkedIn and as soon as I asked him about the shareholder meeting thing he stopped responding to me.

Comment: I did receive two communications from their corporate secretary, the most recent was in 2013 regarding an election of members of the board directors. The contact information on this letter is outdated, but I believe the same person still holds that same office.

Answer (score 2):

A large publicly traded company will have a "shareholder relations" department.   Check the website or call the main office and speak with someone there.  You should also be receiving ballots to vote on shareholder-decided issues such as electing directors, appointing auditors, etc.  The invitation is usually included with the election information.

Comment: This is true for a large publicly traded company, but it's not clear to be from the question if that's the kind of company being talked about here.

Comment: Hi, the company is not public. They are based in California but Incorporated in Delaware. The company is about 150 employees and there isn't anything like a shareholder relations department. I received shares in exchange for some work I did for them when they were just starting out.